# How many Tantra (Sakta Agamas) texts are there?

Tags: tantra

I am only talking about Sakta Agamas (Tantra). How many texts are there? I somewhere read the number is 64. But I am not sure. I do not have any reference also. For example, we had a clear idea of how many Vedas we have. What about Tantra? If possible, please mention the name of those texts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer given by @AnubrataBit is complete, I find it important to list the 64 tantras as stated in Sarvollāsatantram composed by Sarvānandanātha.

> अनन्तो देवदेवी च अनन्तं तन्त्रमेब च।
> गदितुं नैव शक्नोमि ब्रह्माण्डान्तेडपि पार्वति॥

There are infinite gods & goddesses, thus there are infinitely many tantras. Although I have knowledge of this whole universe I would be unable to describe all tantras. (Ullas 2, Shloka 4)

> तवाज्ञया महेशानि लोकानां त्राणहेतवे ।
> चतुःषष्टीणि तन्त्राणि मयैवोक्तानि कामिनि ॥

O Maheshani, As you ordered me to, for the people of this world to attain the moksha, I had already listed the sixty-four types of tantras! (Ullas 2, Shloka 5)

**The list:** (Ullas 2, Shloka 6-20)

> *Kālītantra, Muṇḍamālātantra, Tārātantra, Nirvāṇatantra, Śivasāratantra Vīratantra, Lijhlārcanatantra, Latārcanatantra, Tōḍalatantra, Nīlatantra, Rādhātantra, Viśvasāratantra, Bhairava- tantra, Bhairavītantra, Siddhēśvaratantra, Mātr̥kābhēdatantra, Samayātantra, Guptasādhanatantra, Mātr̥kā-tantra, Māyātantra, Mahāmāyātantra, Akṣayātantra, Kumārītantra, Mahatūtantra, Kulārṇavatantra, Kālikākulasarvasvatanatra, Kālikākalpatantra, Varāhītantra, Yōginītantra, Yoginīhadaya-tantra, Sanatr̥kumāratantra, Tripurāsāratantra, Yōginī Vijayatantra, Mālinītantra, Kukkuṭatantra, Śrīgaṇēśatantra, Bhūtatantra, Uḍḍīśatantra, Kāmadhēnutantra, Vīrabhadratantra, Vāmakēśvaratantra, Kulacūṛāmaṇitantra, Bhāvacūṛāmaṇitantra, Jñānārṇavatantra, Varadātantra, Tantra-cintāmaṇitantra, Kālīvilāsatantra, Hansatantra, Cidāmbarataṭatantra, Vijñāpanatantra, Phētkāriṇītantra, Nityātantra, Uttaratantra, Nārāyaṇītantra, Urdhvāmnāyakatantra, Jñānadvīpa-tantra, Gautamīyatantra, Nirūttaratantraṁ, Gāndharvatantra, Kujjikātantra, Tantramuktāvalītantra, Br̥hatatantra, Śrīkramatantra, Yonitantra & Kaamaakhyaatantra.*

Edit:

In the **[Saundarya Lahari](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/books/Quintessence-Soundarya-Lahari.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjLhoTrgfjwAhXK4jgGHQtyAnEQFjACegQIIxAC&usg=AOvVaw0Xeaa4544q6km_FIiUY2FG)** we find a mention to the 64 Tantras, but their names have not been stated:

> चतुष्षष्टया तन्‍त्रे! सकलमतिसन्धाय' भुवनं स्थितस्तत्तत्सिद्धिप्रसवपरतन्त्रेः पशुपतिः ।
> पुनस्त्वन्निबेन्धादखिलपूरुषार्थैकघटना-स्वतन्त्रं ते तन्त्रं क्षतितलमवातीतरदिदम्‌ ॥ ३१ ॥

> The Lord of all souls, Pasupathi, Did create the sixty four tantras, Each leading to only one desired power, And started he his relaxation.. But you goaded him mother, To create in this mortal world. Your tantra called Sri vidya. Which grants the devotee, All powers that give powers, Over all the states in life.

However in the [commentry of Lakshmidhara](https://archive.org/details/SaundaryaLahariAKuppaswami/Saundarya%20Lahari%20A%20Kuppaswami%201%20of%202/page/n277/mode/2up), list of the 64 tantras is mentioned:

> **चतुष्षष्टितन्त्राणि चतुश्शत्याम**--
> चतुष्षष्टिश्व तन्‍त्राणि मातॄणामुत्तमानि च। महामायाशम्बरं च योगिनीजालशम्बरम्‌ ॥ तत्त्वशभ्बरकं चैव भैरवाष्टकमेव च । बहुरूपा्ष्टकं चैव यमळाष्टकमेव च ॥ चन्द्रज्ञानं मालिनी च महासम्मोहनं तथा । वामजुष्टं महादेवं वातुलं वातुलोत्तरम्‌ ॥ हृध्देदं तन्त्रमेदं च गुह्यातन्त्रे च कामिकम्‌। कलावादं कलासारं तथान्यत्‌ कुण्डिकामतम्‌ ॥ मतोत्तरं च वीणाख्यं त्रोतलं त्रोतलोत्तरम्‌ । पञ्चामृतं रूपभेदं भूतोड्डामरमेव च ॥ कुलसारं कुलोड्डीशं कुल्चूडामणिस्तथा । सर्वज्ञानोत्तरं चैव महुकाळीमतं तथा ॥ अरुणेशं मोदिनीशं विकुण्ठेश्वरमेव च । पूर्वपश्चिमदक्षं च उत्तरं च निरुत्तरम्‌ ॥ विमलं विमलोत्थं च देवीमतमत:परम्‌ ॥

> 1. Maha Maya Shaambara 2. Yogini Jaala Shambara 3. Tatwa Shaambara or the Vidya with the ability and facility of awakening and relolving among the Tatvas 4 - 11. Bhairava Ashtakas 12-19. Bahu
>    Ruupaashtakas 20-27. Yamalaashtakaas 28. Cchandra Vigjnaana 29. Maalini Vidya enabling the crossing of Oceans 30. Maha Sammohana 31. Vaamajushta 32. Maha Deva 33. Baatula 34 Baatulottara 35. Hridbheda 36. Tantra Bheda 37. Guhya Yaatra 38. Kaamika 39. Kalaa Vaada 40. Kalaa Saara 41. Kubjo Maata 42. Tan trottara 43. Beenaa Tantra 44. Shrotala 45. Shrotalottara 46. Panchaamrita 47. Rupabheda 48.Bhutongkaamara 49. Kulasaara 50. Kulongkeesha 51. Kula Choodaamani 52.Sarva Jnaanottara 53.
>    Maha Kaali Mata 54. Arunesha 55. Modineesha / Mohineesha 56. Vikuntheshvara 57. Purvaamnaaya 59. Dakshinaamnaaya 60. Uttaraamnaaya 61. Niruttaamnaaya 62. Vimala 63. Vimalotya 64. Devi Matha

Comment: If you can mention the chapter and verse number it will be very useful.

Comment: got it. 2nd chapter

Comment: I added the chapter and verse numbers. Hope, you won't mind. Thank you so much for this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Arthur Avalon mentioned in the *Principles of Tantra*(English translation of the Bengali work *Tantratattva* written by his guru Shivachandra Vidyârnava) that each *Krântâ* has it's own 64 sets of Shâktâgamas. There are 3 *Krântâ*s,  which makes a total of 192 Shâktâgamas.

For Vishnukrântâ, these 64 Shâktâgamas are :

*Siddheshvara Tantra, Kâlî Tantra, Kulârnava Tantra, Jnanârnava Tantra, Nîla Tanta, Phetkârinî Tantra, Devî Âgama, Uttara Tantra, Shrîkrama Tantra, Siddhayâmala Tantra, Matsyasûkta, Siddhasâra Tantra, Siddhasârasvata Tantra, Vârâhî Tantra, Yoginî Tantra, Ganeshavimarshinî Tantra, Nityâ Tantra, Shivâgama, Châmundâ Tantra, Mundamâlâ Tantra, Hamsamaheshvara Tantra, Niruttara Tantra, Kulaprakâshaka Tantra, Devîkalpa Tantra, Gândharva Tantra, Kriyâsâra Tantra, Nibandha Tantra, Svatantra Tantra, Sammohana Tantra, Tantrarâja Tantra, Lalitâ Tantra, Râdhâ Tantra, Mâlinî Tantra, Rudrayâmala Tantra, Brihatshrîkrama Tantra, Gavâksha Tantra, Sukumudinî Tantra, Vishuddheshvara Tantra, Mâlinîvijaya Tantra, Samayâchâra Tantra, Bhairavî Tantra, Yoginîhridaya Tantra, Bhairava Tantra, Sanatkumâra Tantra, Yoni Tantra, Tantrântara Tantra, Navaratneshvara Tantra, Kulachudâmani Tantra, Bhâvachudâmani Tantra, Devaprakâsha Tantra, Kâmâkhyâ Tantra, Kâmadhenu Tantra, Kumârî Tantra, Bhûtadâmara Tantra, Yâmala Tantra, Brahmayâmala Tantra, Vishvasâra Tantra, Mahâkâlasamhita, Kuloddîsha Tantra, Kulâmrita Tantra, Kubjikâ Tantra, Yantrachitâmani Tantra, Kâlîvilâsa Tantra, Mâyâ Tantra*

For Rathakrântâ, these 64 Shâktâgamas are :

*Chinmaya Tantra, Matsyasûkta, Mahishamardinî Tantra, Matrikâbheda Tantra, Hamsamaheshvara Tantra, Meru Tantra, Mahânîla Tantra, Mahânirvâna Tantra, Bhûtadâmara Tantra, Devadâmara Tantra, Vîjachintâmani Tantra, Ekajatâ Tantra, Vâsudevarahasya, Brihadgautamîya Tantra, Varnoddhriti Tantra, Chhâyânîla Tantra, Brihadyonî Tantra, Brahmajnana Tantra, Garuda Tantra, Varnavilâsâ Tantra, Bâlâvilasa Tantra, Purascharanachandrika, Purascharanollâsa, Panchadashî Tantra, Pichchhillâ Tantra, Prapanchasârâ Tantra, Parameshvara Tantra, Navaratneshvara Tantra, Nâradîya Tantra, Nâgârjuna Tantra, Yogasâra Tantra, Dakshinâmûrtî Tantra, Yogasvarodaya Tantra, Yakshinî Tantra, Svarodaya Tantra, Jnânabhairava Tantra, Âkâshabhairava Tantra, Râjarâjeshvari Tantra, Revatî Tantra, Sârasa Tantra, Indrajâla Tantra, Krikalasadîpikâ, Kankâlamâlinî Tantra, Kâlottama Tantra, Yakshadâmara Tantra, Sarasvatî Tantra, Saradâ Tantra, Shaktisangama Tantra, Shaktikâgamasarvasya, Sammohanî Tantra, Âchârasâra Tantra, Chînâchâra Tantra, Shadâmnâya Tantra, Karâlabhairava Tantra, Shodha Tantra, Mahâlakshmî Tantra, Kaivalya Tantra, Kulasadbhâva Tantra, Siddhitâdhârî Tantra, Kritisâra Tantra, Kâlabhairava Tantra, Uddâmaresha Tantra, Mahâkâlasamhita, Bhûtabhairava Tantra*

For Ashvakrântâ, these 64 Shâktâgamas are:

*Bhûtasuddhi Tantra, Guptadikshâ Tantra, Brihatsâra Tantra, Tattvassâra Tantra, Varnasâra Tantra, Kriyâsâra Tantra, Gupta Tantra, Guptasâra Tantra, Brihattodala Tantra, Brihannirvâna Tantra, Brihadkankâlamâlinî Tantra, Siddha Tantra, Kalâ Tantra, Shiva Tantra, Sârâtsâra Tantra, Gaurî Tantra, Yoga Tantra, Dharmaka Tantra, Tattvachintamani Tantra, Bindu Tantra, Mahâyoginî Tantra, Brihadyoginî Tantra, Shivârchanâ Tantra, Shabara Tantra, Shûlinî Tantra, Mahâmâlinî Tantra, Moksha Tantra, Brihanmâlinî Tantra, Mahâmoksha Tantra, Brihanmoksha Tantra, Gopî Tantra, Bhûtalipi Tantra, Kâminî Tantra, Mohinî Tantra, Mohana Tantra, Samîrana Tantra, Kâmakeshava Tantra, Mahâvîra Tantra, Chudâmanî Tantra, Gurvâchanî Tantra, Gopîra Tantra, Tikshna Tantra, Mangalâ Tantra, Kâmaratna Tantra, Gopalîlâmrita Tantra, Brahmânanda Tantra, Chîna Tantra, Mahâniruttara Tantra, Bhûteshvara Tantra, Gâyatrî Tantra, Vishuddheshvara Tantra, Yogârnava Tantra, Bherundâ Tantra, Mantrachintâmani Tantra, Yantrachudâmani Tantra, Viddyullatâ Tantra, Bhuvaneshvarî Tantra, Lîlâvatî Tantra, Brihadchîna Tantra, Kuranja Tantra, Jayarâdhâmâdhava Tantra, Ujjashâka Tantra, Dhûmâvatî Tantra, Shivâ Tantra*

Some texts don't appear in the list but are considered higly authorative. These are  *Brihannîla Tantra, Todala Tantra, Varadâ Tantra, Tripurâ Tantra, Rasollâsa Tantra, Dattâtreya Tantra, Yogasârârnava Tantra, Hamsa Tantra, Sarvollâsa Tantra, Guptasâdhana Tantra, Virabhadra Tantra, Advaita Tantra, Anûttama Tantra,  Rahasya Tantra, Yogeshvara Tantra, Guru Tantra, Latâtantra, Urdhdâmnâya Tantra, Nirvâna Tantra, Âgamasarvasya, Kâlîkulasarvasya, Shyamârahasya, Nigamakalpadruma, Annadâkalpa, Kaulavali, Mahâchînâcharakrama, Nirvânakramadîpikâ, Kaulikârchanadîpikâ*

The *Vârâhî Tantra* also cites the following texts as Shâktâgamas :

*Nîlapatâkâ Tantra, Vâmakeshvara Tantra, Mritunjaya Tantra, Yogârnava Tantra, Kâmeshvarî Tantra, Haragaurî Tantra, Kâtyayanî Tantra, Pratyangirâ Tantra, Tripurârnava Tantra, Mridânî Tantra, Nârâyani Tantra*

The 6 *damara* texts(*Yogadâmara, Shivadâmara, Durgâdâmara, Sârasvatadâmara, Gandharvadâmara, Brahmadâmara*) & 6 *yâmala* texts(*Âdiyâmala, Brahmayâmala, Vishnuyâmala, Rudrayâmala, Ganeshayâmala, Adityayâmala*) have also been cited by the *Vârâhî Tantra*. Outside these 6 *yâmala*s, there also exists *Umâyâmala, Skandayâmala* & *Jayadrathayâmala*.

Some *nibandha*s like *Shrîvidyârnava Tantra* of Vidyâranya, *Shâradâtilaka Tantra* of Lakshmana Deshikendra along with it's various commentaries, *Shâktânandataranginî* & *Târârahasya* of Brahmânanda Girî, *Mantramahodadhi* of Mahîdhara, *Brihat Tantrasâra* of  Krishnânanda Âgamavâgishâ, *Târâbhaktisudhârnava, Târinîkrama, Mahâvidya Prakarana, Târâparicharyâ* of Narasimha Thakura, *Tripurasundarî Tantra, Traipurasiddhântaprakarana* of Amritânandanâtha, *Traipurasârasamuchchaya* of Nâgabhatta, *Parashurâma Kalpasûtra* along with the *Saubhagyashubhodaya* commentary by Râmeshvara, *Kâlikâbhaktirasâyana, Kaulagajamardana, Tantrasiddhântakaumudî, Dakshinâchâradîpikâ, Mantrachandrikâ, Yantrachandrikâ* of Kâshînatha Bhatta alongside the works of Râghavânanda, Virûpâksha, Govindabhatta like *Râmârchanachandrikâ, Tripurâsârasamuchchaya, Svachchhandasamgrahasârasamuchchaya, Bhuvaneshvarîpârijâta, Mantramuktâvalî, Mantratantraprakâsha, Somabhujangâvalî* are worth mentionable in this regard.

Although the Vaishnava Âgama canon includes Panchâratra texts, centain Tântrika Vaishnava texts which don't fall under the Panchâratra list are revered by Shâktas of Bengal. These are the *Gautamiya Tantra*, *Bṛhadgautamiya Tantra*, *Sammohana Tantra*, *Sanatkumāra Tantra*, *Urdhvāmnāya Tantra*, *Māheśvara Tantra* & *Krishnayâmala Tantra*. Besides Âgamavâgishâ also quoted from Vaishnava Tântrika nibandhas like *Râmârchanachandrikâ, Krishnârchanachandrika* & *Govindavrindâvana*.

Comment: If available in online format, can you please hyperlink  the source(s) in your answer itself ?

Comment: @vivikta you can find it [here](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.3580/page/n103/mode/2up).

Comment: @Proxy - Thank you

Comment: Thx this answer is quite helpful 

Comment: Can you please tell the chapter and page number where these krantas are mentioned?

Comment: I could not find the name of these three krantas.

Answer (score 1):

There are sixty-four most important Tantras. However, in addition to these sixty-four Tantras, there are other Tantras as well.

Kulacūḍāmaṇi Tantra (I.4-13) gives us a list of the "sixty-four most excellent Tantras". Vāmakeśvara Tantra (I.13-21) also gives a list of "the sixty-four excellent Tantras of the Mother". These two lists are quite similar, but not identical. Few names are different. Also, remember that the list differs slightly between different manuscripts of the same Tantra. Here is the list mentioned in the Kulacūḍāmaṇi Tantra -

- 1. Mahāmāya
- 2. Mahāsārasvata (*)
- 3. Yoginijālaśambara
- 4. Tattvaśambara
- 5 - 12. Bhairavāṣṭaka (Eight Tantras dedicated to eight Bhairavas: Asitāṅga, Ruru, Caṇḍa, Krodha, Unmatta, Kapālī, Bhīṣaṇa, Saṃhāra)
- 13 - 20. Bahurūpāṣṭaka (Eight Tantras of seven Mātrikās [Brāhmi, Maheshvari, Kumāri, Vaishnavī, Varāhi, Indrānī and Cāmundā)] and Śivadūtī)
- 21 - 28. Yāmalaṣṭaka (Brahmayāmala, Viṣṇuyāmala, Rudrayāmala, Lakṣmīyāmala, Skandayāmala, Gaṇeśayāmala, Grahayāmala, Umāyāmala)
- 29. Tantrajñāna (*)
- 30. Vāsuki (*)
- 31. Mahāsammohana (*)
- 32. Hṛdbheda
- 33. Mahāsukṣma (*)
- 34. Guhya
- 35. Kāmika
- 36. Kālapāda
- 37. Kālasāra
- 38. Kubjikā
- 39. Vāhana (*)
- 40. Vinā
- 41. Troḍala
- 42. Troḍalattara
- 43. Pañcāmṛta
- 44. Rūpabheda
- 45. Bhūtoḍāmara
- 46. Kulosāra
- 47. Kuloḍḍiśa
- 48. Viśvātmaka (*)
- 49. Sarvajñāttora
- 50. Vāhonattara (*)
- 51. Mahālakṣmīmata
- 52. Siddhayogīśvarīmata
- 53. Kurūpikāmata
- 54. Devarūpikāmata
- 55. Sarvavīramata
- 56. Vimalāmata
- 57. Pūrvamnāya, Paścimāmnāya, Dakṣināmnāya and Uttarāmnāya
- 58. Niruttara
- 59. Vaiśeṣika
- 60. Jñānarṇva
- 61. Śivabāli (*)
- 62. Aruṇeśa
- 63. Mohinīśa
- 64. Viśuddheśvara

*Vāmakśvara list corresponds with the above list except for the nine items marked with an asterisk. Vāmakeśvara gives the following names in those places -
Śambara, Mahocchuṣma, Vātula, Vātulottara, Tantrabheda, Tantrottara, Kulacūḍāmaṇi, Mahākālīmata, Vīrābalī

Apart from these Tantras, there are other Tantras as well.

> "Such as these Tantras and there are also countless others." - Kulacūḍāmaṇi Tantra I.13"

> "These are the scriptures and there are a vast number of other Tantras besides." - *Vāmakeśvara Tantra I.21*

References -

1. Kulacudamani Tantra edited by Girishchandra Vedantatirtha (p.4-5)
2. The Kulacudamani Tantra and Vamakesvara Tantra by Louis M. Finn